# Bitmap is null after creating it in Android Java

Tags: android

I get an error of

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.helpers.PrinterHelper.getTrasparentBitmapCopy(PrinterHelper.java:145)
        at com.kotlin.ambulantlcs.helpers.PrinterHelper.convertStringToImage(PrinterHelper.java:133)
```

when I run this code in Android Java

```
public static void convertStringToImage(Activity activity)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(12);

        canvas.drawText("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sed Actum Malo", 10, 10, paint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.restore();

        int iRet = ftplib.printPicture(bitmap, FTPAndroidLib.DITHER_NONDITHERING, bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth()); ===> ERROR IS HERE
       
    }
```

I am trying to create an image of a text that I create programmatically because I will be joining it to another image later. But before I do that, I am printing it out first.

### Edit

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(9);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(9);

        canvas.drawText("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sed Actum Malo", 0, 50, paint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.restore();

int iRet = ftplib.printPicture(bitmap, FTPAndroidLib.DITHER_NONDITHERING, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

### Edit 2

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(350, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextSize(20);

        Log.i("TAG", message);
        canvas.drawText("Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sed Actum Malo", 0, 50, paint);
        canvas.save();


         int iRet = ftplib.printPicture(bitmap, FTPAndroidLib.DITHER_NONDITHERING, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: I guess you restoring canvas earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will help you, just try it.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);  // White background color of canvas.
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);  // Text align left
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextSize(12);
    canvas.drawPaint(paint); 
    
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Black text color
    paint.setTextSize(20); 
    canvas.drawText("Put Your Text Here", 10, 10, paint);

    int iRet = ftplib.printPicture(bitmap, FTPAndroidLib.DITHER_NONDITHERING, bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth());

    canvas.restore();
```

Comment: I don't get the null anymore. Can you please make it that I get a white background and a black text? Thank you so munch.

Comment: change this value canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: Please see my Edit. I get all black. Meaning, my canvas is black and so is the text.